# Stop propagating event to the parent in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to implement a collapsible in bootstrap dropdown. After expanding a collapsible the dropdown closes as this is default behaviour of dropdown.

[Scenario 1](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lz6gz3b/55/)

Html code as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li>
         <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                  Collapsible group of links
                  </a>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Group link 1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Group link 2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Group link 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

When I stop the event propagation in order to keep dropdown open always, collapsible stops working.

[Scenario 2](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lz6gz3b/56/)

How can I prevent event propagation only for the dropdown? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to `stopPropagation()` for a specific event, target or function.

Here's a workaround. Stop propagation and toggle the menu by yourself.

```js
$('a[href="#collapseOne"]').on('click', function(e){
  $($(this).attr('href')).toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li>
         <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                  Collapsible group of links
                  </a>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Group link 1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Group link 2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Group link 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```